# extension when a screen is created a button will automatically be put next to the save button at the bottom of the screen

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

lightswitch extensions: i need to make an extension so that each time a screen is created a button will automatically be put next to the save button at the bottom of the screen without having to add a button using the designer of lightswitch the extension will handle that. Is something like that possible ? if not what are exactly the things i can do with lightswitch ?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use this extension:

http://janvanderhaegen.wordpress.com/2011/09/11/extensions-made-easy-adding-custom-commands-global-commands-and-new-command-groups-to-the-lightswitch-button-ribbon/

it'll probably make your life easier

Answer (score 2):

i found what i was looking for here :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7848af2b-d57d-4189-86ef-1e68cd3754f3/how-can-i-create-a-button-that-is-available-for-every-screen-in-my-lightswitch-application
i needed to expose the i commandshell